# A compound word with Latin or Greek roots

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

I seek a word with the meaning of "a (compound) word of Latin or Greek origin", as in:

> [...] words are commonly used in scientific terminology.

The word itself doesn't have to be a compound word of Latin or Greek origin, but I suppose it would be nice if it were. It doesn't necessarily have to have both Latin or Greek origin, just one (or both) of those.

Comment: I don't think anything will get the idea across better than *compound words of Latin and/or Greek origin are commonly used in scientific terminology.*

Comment: 'Neo-classical compound' fits the bill.

Comment: I would call them Greco-Latin words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My choice would be 'neo-classical compound', i.e. a compound where at least one of the component bases is a combining form, usually of Greek or Latin origin.

Such compounds figure prominently in scientific terminology, as well as in learned vocabulary generally: "astronaut", pseudonym", "psychology" and the like.

Answer (score 1):

The word you probably need is ***classical*** - *b. gen. Of, relating to, or characteristic of Greek or Roman antiquity.* (OED sense 1b)

Comment: And 'compound' has classical compound roots: Latin 'compon[ere]' = to put with.